# Spring Batch/ Integration - receive message

Tags: spring-integration

My java process is kicked off first & it has to wait till the jms message is available to activeMQ and then it should read the JMS message and execute the java program. I wanto use JMSTemplate. Once executed, it should exit.
can I have  like this:
          can I use while(msg==null) whithin which I can receive msg and process the program. At the end I will use System.exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so.

Also pay attention to this in the `JmsTemplate`:

```
/**
 * Receive a message synchronously from the default destination, but only
 * wait up to a specified time for delivery.
 * <p>This method should be used carefully, since it will block the thread
 * until the message becomes available or until the timeout value is exceeded.
 * <p>This will only work with a default destination specified!
 * @return the message received by the consumer, or {@code null} if the timeout expires
 * @throws JmsException checked JMSException converted to unchecked
 */
Message receive() throws JmsException;
```